# Errors In Code Swift / Xcode / Postman

Tags: ios, xcode, postman

I'm a beginner in iOS. What I'm trying to do is: 
getting data from server through postman, copy the code from postman & past it into Xcode. Xcode shows errors, and I am stuck. Because I am a beginner I can't get rid of these errors.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController/*, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol */{


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }


        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "Basic Og==",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "212506d2-d231-a462-8f6a-b0ec38f884e4"
        ]


        let postData = NSData(data: "{ flight_type: "Arrival" , fromdate: "17-Mar-     2017" }".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://<servername>.ashx")! as URL,
                                    cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse!)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()

    }class ViewController: UIViewController/*, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol */{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Basic Og==",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "212506d2-d231-a462-8f6a-b0ec38f884e4"
    ]


    let postData = NSData(data: "{ flight_type: "Arrival" , fromdate: "17-Mar-     2017" }".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://mywallet.pk/api/flightschedule.ashx")! as URL,
                                cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse!)
    }
})

dataTask.resume()

}
```

[Screenshot of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8ax.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import
Please add UIKit at the start of the file.

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting and what are you trying to achieve?